# Meteor Accessing a single item in a collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am very new to not only Meteor but script in general. I am having issues with a program. I have a collection storing times. I want to display each time in it's own div. I have the collection set like this.

```js
Timeslots = new Mongo.Collection('times');
Timeslots.insert({Time: "8:00am"});
Timeslots.insert({Time: "8:30am"});
Timeslots.insert({Time: "9:00am"});
Timeslots.insert({Time: "9:30am"});
```

A helper function

```js
Template.Available.helpers({
    'newtime': function(){
        return Timeslots.find()
    }

});
```

I want to access each time to put it in its own div. So a div for 8:00am one for 8:30 etc.

My template html is

```html
<div class="col-sm-2 available open" id="opentime">
  <h2 class="time">                                                            
    {{#each newtime}}
    <p>{{Time}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </h2>
  <p class="text"></p><br>
  <p class="text"></p><br>
</div>
```

However I have 20 times so 20 different divs. So one how do i access the value in the collection. Second how should I be changing this template so that it accesses the correct div? Thank you for advice and input. I am sure I am way off.

Comment: What do you mean by 'access the value in the collection'? Do you want to transform the Time value?

Comment: Ok so in each dive I want a single value in the collection. So the first div is 8:00, the second 8:30, the 3rd 9:00. So in the collection (and only if my thinking is correct) that is value:0, 1, and 2. The div needs to be tied to a single time. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: it's not quite clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. If you want each time in a separate div, then why not just replace the `p` tag with a `div` tag in the `#each`?

Comment: The html is structured as such

Comment: <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2">

     {{> Available }}

     </div>

     

     <div class="col-sm-2">

     {{> Available }}

     </div>

     

     <div class="col-sm-2"> 
     {{> Available }}
     </div>

     

     <div class="col-sm-2"> 
     {{> Available }}
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-2"> 
     {{> Available }}
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row padding">
     <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2">

     {{> Available }}

     </div>

Comment: if I add the template for each i get every time not just a single time

Comment: that's because you are calling the each loop inside the template. Instead, structure it like my answer below, and wrap the html inside the `Available` template . You don't need 20 divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the div in your each loop:

```
<template name = "Available">
{{#each newtime}}
 <div class="col-sm-2 available open" id="opentime">
            <h2 class="time">                                                             
                 <p{{Time}}</p>
             </h2>
        </div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

And only include once - you shouldn't be hard coding a bunch of divs, that's the kind of work meteor exists to do for you!! :)

This will also allow for reactivity, so you can do things like open another browser window to your app and in the console write `Timeslots.insert({Time: "9:30am"});` and if the insecure and autopublish packages are still included, you can watch the list change in the first browser window.

EDIT: found a couple small errors, such as in the template helper, you need `Timeslots.find({})` with the extra parens inside the brackets. Aslo, in the loop, you are missing a parentheses at `{{Time}}`
Also, be mindful that the code you have currently is adding the times to the DB everytime meteor restarts, which is a lot. You should do a check and see if there is anything in the db, and then add the seed data. To do that use:

```
if (Timeslots.find().count() === 0) { 
  Timeslots.insert({ time: '8:30am' });
  Timeslots.insert({ time: '9:00am' });
 }
```

You can always use `meteor reset` to clear out the db in the meantime.

I've edited your project to get it to where it's doing what I think you want, it's not complete, but it's enough to get you past the block you are at. I took out some of the buttons, but you can add them back, or better yet, just adapt the changes into your own code. You were very close!! The file is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b162junes4usew4/teetimes-master.zip?dl=0

That should be enough to get you started!

Comment: jorjordandan I appreciate the insight. I am very green like I have stated. Your code however gives me an error. I am attempting to build an app to book reservation times. So the multiple divs are one for each time and the user selects the one they want and clicks the button on that div. So the time is for display at the top in the users view and a button below. So you would have 8:00am then button, 9:00am then button. I know i am not making clear sense probably. I have the project on github if anyone want to look at what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: What's the error? What's the link? I can take a look.

Comment: GitHub.com\andyschoenherr\teetimes

Comment: Please forgive the lack of knowledge. This is a project I am doing for class. It's a front end class. I'm using meteor for its db ability where I have had no training. So I'll do my best to describe what's going on. I really appreciate the feedback

Comment: Thank you! One question for you. If I am correct I should run an if statement to only add the times once?

Comment: Yup - I've updated my answer to show what you need to do to make that work correctly

Comment: I added that as well as added the same except for I tried > 1 as well. Changed it to === 0 and its still repeating and adding the times on every refresh

Comment: Oops, should have been a capital T on `Timeslots` in the if statement, fixed it in the answer